# Prove this trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Prove the following trigonometric identity: $16\sin ^2\left(θ\right)\cos ^3\left(θ\right)=2\cos \left(θ\right)-\cos \left(3θ\right)-\cos \left(5θ\right)\:$

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Just develop the both sides in terms of $\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using

1. $2\cos(A)\cos(B)=\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)$, and
2. $\cos^2(A)=\frac{\cos(2A)+1}{2}$
3. $\sin^2(A)=1-\cos^2(A)$

Solution with minimum steps:

Using $(3)$

$$
16\left(1-\cos^2(\theta)\right)\cos^3(\theta)=16\left( \cos(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) - \cos(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\right)
$$

using $(2)$

$$
16\ \cos(\theta)\left(\frac {\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}\right) \left[ 
1-\frac {\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}
 \right]
$$
simplify

$$
-\frac{16}{1}\cos(\theta)\left(\frac {\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}\right) \left[ 
\frac {\cos(2\theta)-1}{2}
 \right]
$$
and
$$
-\frac{16}{4}\cos(\theta)\left[ 
\cos^2(2\theta)-1
 \right]
$$
using $(2)$
$$
-\frac{16}{8}\cos(\theta)\left[ 
\cos(4\theta)-1
 \right]
$$
using $(1)$
$$
2\cos(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)\cos(4\theta) = 2\cos(\theta)-\cos(5\theta)-\cos(3\theta)
$$
**Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2 \alpha=\dfrac{1-\cos 2\alpha}{2}$ and such identity for $\cos^3 \alpha=\dfrac{3\cos \alpha}{4}+\dfrac{\cos 3\alpha}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas

$$\cos A-\cos5A=2\sin3A\sin2A\text{ and }\cos A-\cos3A=2\sin A\sin2A$$

$$\implies\cos A-\cos5A+\cos A-\cos3A=2\sin2A(\sin3A+\sin A)$$

Again using Prosthaphaeresis, $$\sin3A+\sin A=2\sin2A\cos A$$

Finally use $\displaystyle\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$

---

Alternatively,

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas

$$\cos3A+\cos5A=2\cos A\cos4A$$

$$\implies2\cos A-\cos3A-\cos5A=2\cos A(1-\cos4A)=2\cos A(2\sin^22A)$$

Comment: Isn't it enough to post [one copy](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/778242/1543) of your answer?

Comment: @WillieWong, Rectified